# Recent questions drop-down

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

I would like to suggest the implementation of an easy shortcut to access the last 10 (for example) questions that I have participated in (answered or commented on). This could be implemented as a dropdown in the top menu.
Currently I have to go to my profile, and click on the "activity" pane. However, what I'm presented with here is polluted with rejected/approved edits and other "irrelevant" stuff, and thus makes it hard to easily find those questions that I'm "participating" in.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: Why not just add a filter to the `activity` tab?

Comment: @slugster, because the activity tab is one page load and one click away unless you are on your profile. But it would be an improvement though. I would still prefer a shortcut list that was always accessible though.