# My Recent Questions drop-down next to inbox, achievements

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

I leave a browser tab open to the C# tag page on StackOverflow.  It would be really nice if, from this or any page on SO, I could quickly get to a list of questions I've most recently asked, answered, or commented on.  I think a drop-down next to the inbox and achievements drop-downs would be ideal.  This is sort of like the "all actions" tab on my profile page, except that's one page and multiple clicks away from the page I typically have open, and I wouldn't want to see *all activity*, just one link per question I've interacted with.

Often, even when I don't have notifications about these questions, I want to check back to see if there are newer comments or answers.  As it is, it's very easy to lose track of the questions I'm interested in.  I can scroll through the C# tag page looking for visited links, except they fall off the bottom of the page as newly modified questions come in, and at least on SO, the visited links are barely distinguishable visibly from unvisited links.

Edit: this is essentially a duplicate of [another meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80068/recent-questions-drop-down?rq=1); I didn't see that one when I was typing this up.